# Is there a way to write custom fractions in this format: ½, ⅘, ⅞, etc.?

Tags: math-mode

As the title says,

> Is there a way to write custom fractions in this format: ½, ⅘, ⅞, etc.?

by adding some packages or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\begin{document}
    \sfrac{1}{2}, \sfrac{4}{5},
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [nicefrac](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac) package to do this.

Comment: Sorry, but I have already accepted the other answer! Anyways, +1 and thanks for the alternative approach!